# java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\nirma\Language\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\support\coreui'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having this issue in the android studio. The app runs fine 1 or 2 times but then it starts giving this error. How can I solve this problem?

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\nirma\Language\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\support\coreui'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your install of Android Studio is unable to delete that temporary folder, likely due to a permissions issue. You will need to delete that folder manually via Windows Explorer, using admin privileges if required. Your builds should complete properly again after that.

Comment: Hehe, it happens sometime. I just re-hit the  build&run button without doing anything and it just works 

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning and rebuilding my project worked fine for me.

Comment: This looks like an advice rather than an actual answer to the question. Please use comments to give advices